# Android: intent passed to an activity by notifications......i don't get the right extras in the intent

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent, flags

Hi i'm facing this problem. I have an application with 2 activities:
-Activity A (Main activity) showing a list of cars
-If you click on an item list the Activity B is started showing car's details.

From within activity B you can download info related to that car, a service C in charge of the download is started and a notification is added to the notification bar. If you click the notification you are supposed to see Activity B showing details related to that specific car.

My problem is the following: activity B gets an intent with this extra: carID
So in onCreate it reads this extra and ask the db for that specific car details.
When i call Activity B from activity A everything works fine. But when i call activity B from the notification bar it doesn't. It always get details about the first car i chose. 
So for example, i download Ferrari details, and then Lamborghini details....

In my notification i will see 2 notifications, but both of them open activity B showing Ferrari details.

This is how i create the notifications inside the Service C:

```
int icon = icona;  
CharSequence tickerText = message;              
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         
Context context = getApplicationContext();      
CharSequence contentTitle = message;  
CharSequence contentText = appName;      
Intent notificationIntent;
notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("carId", carId);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOT_ID, notification);
```

and this is how i receive the intent in Activity B:

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
appId = myIntent.getIntExtra("carId", 0);
```

At the beginning i didn't receive any intent at all from the notification.....then i added PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT as you can see above and i get it, but it always the first one. I have verified, and i add the correct carId to each intente but i get another one instead......and each time a open the notification this log message appears:

startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=market.finestraprincipale/.ApplicationActivity bnds=[0,101][320,165] (has extras) }

Can someone help me pls....

Comment: Is the ID = 0 you always get?

Comment: At the beginnig i got alway id = 0.......then i canged this line PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0); to PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); and now i get a value but it's always the same.......probably the id in the last intent fired....but i inserted differents ids in each intent :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Original answer revised, see edit history for it)*

I'm not actually sure, which part of your system is malfunctioning so I post my test code here, which I tested to work correctly. First there is `MyService`, then `TestActivity` which displays the car details in `DetailsActivity`:

**CarService.java**

```java
public class CarService extends IntentService
{
    public CarService()
    {
        super("CarService");
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras == null)
        {
            Log.e("CarService", "Service onHandleIntent null extras");
            return;
        }

        int carId = extras.getInt("carId");
        String carName = extras.getString("name");
        Log.i("CarService", "Service onHandleIntent car = " + carName + " with ID = " + Integer.toString(carId));

        Intent notificationIntent;
        notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("carId", carId);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, carId, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, carName, System.currentTimeMillis());
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), carName, "Car Details", pending);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(carId, notif);
    }
}
```

**TestActivity.java** (your main activity)

```java
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.launch);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override public void onClick(View v)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class));
    }
}
```

**test.xml** (layout for TestActivity.java)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" a:id="@+id/layout_root" a:orientation="vertical" a:layout_width="fill_parent" a:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView a:id="@+id/test_value"  a:text="Main..." a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button a:id="@+id/launch" a:text="Details" a:layout_width="100dp" a:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**DetailsActivity.java** (car details listed here + launches CarService + notifications lead back to here)

```java
public class DetailsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private String[] cars = new String[]{"Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Lada", "Nissan", "Opel", "Bugatti"};
    private int id = 0;


    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doit);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            final int id = extras.getInt("carId");
            Log.i("DetailsActivity", "Car ID: " + id);
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_value);
            tv.setText("Car ID = " + Integer.toString(id) + ", which is " + cars[id%6]); // id%6 prevents a crash with the string array when clicking test button over 6 times
        }
    }

    @Override public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CarService.class);
        intent.putExtra("carId", id);
        intent.putExtra("name", cars[id%6]); // id%6 prevents a crash with the string array when clicking test button over 6 times
        startService(intent);
        ++id;
    }
}
```

**details.xml** (layout for TestActivity.java)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" a:orientation="vertical" a:layout_width="fill_parent" a:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView a:id="@+id/test_value" a:text="No details yet: click the button." a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button a:id="@+id/doit" a:text="Test" a:layout_width="100dp" a:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope all that works correctly as I did make some minor changes on the fly.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. They didn't get any extras, cause they didn't set this flag PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, but i did. So it actually refreshes my extras with the new ones each time i fires a notification, but then it uses only the latest extra cause for android there is no difference among the intents inside my notifications, and so it always uses the last....have i got the point? So how can i make all my intents unique?

Comment: Ok, I see the difficulty here. I'll try to make a test project to see how this works out. It'll take some minutes for I have to construct the Service too.

Comment: Btw, do you bind the service to the activity?

Comment: Where do you receive the Intent in activity B? In `onCreate` or somewhere else?

Comment: Is your code for creating the notification in your Service inside `onCreate`, `onStart`, or `onBind`?

Comment: Thank you so much.....it's like if it used always the same pending intent instead of creating differents each time i fire a notifications. SO basically it 's like if it only changed the extras  of the notificationIntent inside the only one  pending intent.....instead i need to have inside each notification a different pendingIntent with inside a notificationIntent with some extras....

Comment: In on create i do Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
appId = myIntent.getIntExtra("carId", 0);
and it always call onCreate cause when i click on my notification i get this message  startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=market.finestraprincipale/.ApplicationActivity bnds=[0,101][320,165] (has extras) } and so a new activity is called....

Comment: a actually use an Intentservice, so my code is inside onHandleIntent

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. Could you show me the code you use in activity B to launch the service?

Comment: Do you see two different notifications in the notification bar after clicking to view two different cars?

Comment: Yes i see one different notification for each car.....anyway now it works.....there was this line missing notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
and the idCar inside the pending intent to meke it unique.....i had a 0 instead.....